# contar datos de un array

Tags: laravel

necesito ayuda, estoy creando un contador. el contador cuenta los items que tiene un pedido,
Los datos que debo contar vienen de el modelo **ItemsPedido:**

```
  $pedido = ItemsPedido::where('habitacion_id', 1)->count('id');
```

En ItemsPedido tengo una relacion con el modelo **Pedidos**: Con este modelo puedo obtener el estado del pedido viendo los items que tiene el mismo.

```
    public function estado()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Pedidos', "pedido_id", "id");
}
```

**El problema es que no puedo hacer esta consulta:**

```
      $pedido = ItemsPedido::where('habitacion_id', 1)->where('estado', 1)->count('id');
```

Lo que busco es que también haga el count donde estado sea 1, **viniendo de la relacion con el Modelo Pedidos**

Como puedo hacer esta consulta para que funcione mi **Count**??

Comment: **tira primero un ->get() antes del count().** Y de echo por que pones "id" dentro de count? si cada linea tiene "id" pues solo quieres te te cuente las filas, pon un count() sin nada dentro, será más rapido de efectuarse la consulta.

Comment: @ferter3006  ya, pero lo que busco es que también haga el count donde estado sea 1, viniendo de la relacion con el Modelo Pedidos

Comment: Entonces tienes que poner ->with('estado') para decirle que incluya la relación con la otra tabla. Mira el ejemplo de la documentacion oficial: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#:~:text=%24users%20%3D%20User%3A%3Awith(%27,%7D

Comment: @ferter3006 ya le aplique ->with('estado'). ahora haciendo dd me aparece la relacion, pero como hago para hacer la comparación ('estado', 1) ??

Comment: eso tal y como lo hacias, con el where. Quedaria algo como ->with(estado)->where(estado, 1)->get()

Comment: si no te funciona, tira un whereRelation(estado, 1). Echa un vistazo aquí: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#:~:text=Inline%20Relationship%20Existence%20Queries